# cant work out what code is needed to change scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created the scenes and I want it to change scenes on death so the code should go under `public override void Death()`:

```cs
public class player : Mover
{
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        UpdateMotor(new Vector3(x, y, 0));
    }
    public override void Death()
    {
         (need code here)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the code will be

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("OtherSceneName", LoadSceneMode.Additive);
```

Replace "OtherSceneName" with the scene you want to change to and choose a scene loading mode that suits your needs.